# How to extract specific files from a list of files in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a cell array named list which contain a list of files. I would like to extract only specific files from that list and store them in the same array. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
function [ varargout ] = myFiles( varargin )

list = {'test.m' '.' '..' 'test1.m' 'test2.txt'};

list = strmatch('*.m', list)

end
```

My final list should be like as below, but yeah the indices should suffice.

```
list = test.m  test1.m
```

I am using MATLAB on Windows. Using the pattern in double quotes throws an error.
Tried using \\'s also as escape sequence for (.) and/or (*) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strmatch` is for finding strings that start with a given prefix. Regular expressions aren't supported. For that you want `regexp`, which takes its arguments in the opposite order. Alternatively, if you reverse all your strings, you can use `strmatch('m.',list)` and then reverse the results again to recover the filenames.

Comment: list(strmatch('m.',cellfun(@(x)fliplr(x),list,'UniformOutput',false)))

Comment: This might be more clear: list(strmatch(fliplr('.m'),cellfun(@(x)fliplr(x),list,'UniformOutput',false)))

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) you would need something like so: `.*\.m$`. The *problem* is that unlike the usual search in windows, the `*` means 0 or more repetitions of was preceds it, so doing it on its own will not work.

In this case, I am saying match any character (the `.` means any single character) 0 or more times which is then followed by a `.m` at the end. The `$` specifies that the match must end at the end of the string.

Comment: list = regexp(list,'.*\.m$', 'match')
    celldisp(list)
On trying the above line of code, a 2-d list is created, along with empty cells(which do not match the pattern, ofcourse)